# Difference between Navigator and Helmsman

Tags: star-trek

In *Star Trek,* what is the difference between the navigator and the helmsman? Generally, the helmsman seems to be much more important, or at least does much more manual work. Memory Alpha's descriptions seem to be pretty congruent in both its articles on helmsman and navigator. In the series, the navigators (Sulu, Tom Paris, Keyla Detmer, etc.) seem to have a much bigger and more important job (handling attitude, warp drive, etc.)

What is the difference between navigator and helmsman?

Comment: Not sure many starships had a navigator position. It seems like most have the navigator and helm combined into one role

Comment: Memory Alpha describes Detmer as the helm officer. Paris is described is the "flight control officer".

Comment: "Generally, the helmsman seems to be much more important" — well, they're a man, so yes of course. But I suspect both of them just press the "Hey computer, do what the captain just said" button while trying to make it look a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: "In the series, the navigators (Sulu, Tom Paris, Keyla Detmer, etc.) seem to have a much bigger and more important job (handling attitude, warp drive, etc.)" - at least Paris and Detmer did have bigger problems "handling their attitude" at times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Helmsman/Navigator](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Helmsman) (Memory Alpha)

> The **helmsman** (or helm officer) was the Starfleet crewperson who operated the helm console on 22nd and 23rd century Federation starships.
>
> The **helmsman** of those vessels worked in concert with the **navigator**, who plotted the ship's course. On the USS Enterprise, the **helmsman** controlled both the speed and attitude of the ship, as well as the ship's weapon and shield systems.

Note:

> By the 24th century, the **helm** and **navigation** stations became combined as the **flight control officer** position. Also, control of weapons and defenses is usually handled by the tactical station or the operations officer, rather than their 23rd century equivalents, under the control of the **helmsman**.

This later merging of the roles might be responsible for some confusion.

Comment: How did the helmsman handle _**flight and tactical at the same time?!**_

Comment: @SovereignInquiry By sliding sliders and pressing buttons.  Technical use of the Enterprise wasn't really explored or explained on Kirk's Enterprise.

Comment: It's notable that airplane flight crews back in the 1960's (when Star Trek first came out) included a few extra people in the cockpit, one of whom was the Flight Navigator, a position which became largely obsolete by the mid-70's.  It's likely the show was modeling on such real-world examples of the time, as were the later shows, which were created long after Navigators were a relic of the past, much like the Radio Operator - you'll notice there was no equivalent to anyone having Uhura's job in the later shows either.

Comment: I’m guessing due to more advanced computers on the “D” and 24th century vessels, the navigator position dwindled into obscurity. So tactical positions replaced it. Although I’m curious as to what the left forward station was for that Data always used. Some sort of Ops or Science station?

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Data is described as the *Enterprise*'s operations officer, so presumably Ops. As I recall, the bridge science stations are the big ones behind Worf.

Comment: I’ve often wondered what “Ops” entails on a Starship. It wouldn’t be security. That’s Worf’s job. Ship operations would fall to Geordi as Chief Engineer.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Ops seems to mostly relate to monitoring internal and external sensors - at least,  that's what Data does in most episodes.

Comment: That’s what Spock did too, so that suggests Ops was probably a new position that made its way in to 24th century vessels too, because Spock was a science officer along with First Officer.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - Ops is basically in charge of making sure that every department has what they need, when they need it, giving priority to the captain's direct orders, bridge operations, shields and weapons. This includes power generation, time on various sensor arrays, shutdown of facilities to perform systems analysis and so forth.

Comment: @Valorum I’m guessing the sensor responsibilities moved to that position from the bridge science officer’s station as Spock was in charge of that as first officer and science officer of the bridge. I can’t recall any mention of Ops officers in TOS, which is why I’m guessing it evolved into a new position on 24th century vessels along with removal of the navigator.

Answer (score 7):

Like today on a ship:

Navigator: Plans how to get from A to B, and makes sure the ship stays on course.

Helmsman:  "Steers" the ship, following the course planned by the navigator.

Comment: Although not incorrect, can you offer any evidence to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum a dictionary?

Comment: And to the point.  Do you really need an in universe source for the definition of common words?  If somebody asks "What's a "sandwich" on Star Trek?" do you need to quote Captain Picard reading a list of instructions for making a sandwich?

Comment: Do you feel the need to have Doctor Crusher's title and job explained with an in universe definition?

Comment: This actually isn't accurate for a military ship in general (my knowledge is from Royal Navy procedures, but it won't differ functionally from other navies): the person on the helm, i.e. with their hands on the wheel, is typically very junior. They follow instructions from the officer of the watch (terminology may vary) who is actually responsible for the ship's course. The OOW will have the route plan, know the current location/tides, adjust for shipping etc. The person on the helm will just repeat back commands and turn the wheel/keep the ship on a given heading as ordered.

Comment: Handover of the helm just involves confirming the current course, speed, engine settings and limitations. Handing over the con (i.e. the OOW's job) involves considerably more than that in terms of navigation (time to next course change), communications, orders, internal activity on the ship, and more.

Comment: While I'm on the topic, a navigator is an specialised officer position and they wouldn't constantly be on the bridge as it's not always needed; the OOW will have planned the course/pilotage for their watch beforehand and would be expected to handle the straightforward navigation/corrections themselves.

Answer (score 4):

The helmsman is like a guy in the driver's seat of a car, his hands on the wheel, his feet on the pedals, controlling where the cars goes and how fast.

The navigator is like a guy in the shotgun seat, reading a map, and telling the driver that he should take the next left turn in order to reach the destination.

Comment: Although not incorrect, can you offer any evidence to back this up?

Comment: This is my understanding of those terms from real-world sailing. A sailing ship's steering wheel cannot be left unattended for even a moment, or the ship will drift. The helmsman holds it, and turns it on instructions from superiors. The navigator is someone who has both hands free to operate navigational instruments, like a sextant, compass, and physical maps. The navigator and captain collaborate, and then instruct the helmsman.